# Console application for mailing does not send last mail

Tags: vb.net, console-application, sendmail

I have the following problem:

I have written little console application that sends emails. It behaves in the following manner:

- when I run this application in debug mode and go through code step by step it sends emails;
- when I run this application in debug mode and do not go through code step by step, last email does not get sent;
- when I build and move application to server and create a task for it, last email does not get sent;
- when I execute application from Windows explorer (double click on .exe file), last email does not get sent;
- when I execute application from command prompt it sends all emails;

What is interesting is that when I put thread.sleep(200) all emails are sent!  Note that I am using this code in my ASP applications and all mails are sent always.  If mail has attachment, it is always sent, even if it is last in queue (but this is another application that works correctly).

Code that I use (class for mailing):

```
 Public Class Mailer

        ' Methods
        Public Sub SendMail()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage(Me.Sender, Me.To, Me.Subject, Me.Body)
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            If Not Me.CC.Trim.Equals("") Then
                mail.CC.Add(Me.CC)
            End If
            If Not Me.BCC.Trim.Equals("") Then
                mail.Bcc.Add(Me.BCC)
            End If
            Dim client As New SmtpClient(Me.MailServer)
            client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.Username, Me.Password)
            client.Send(mail)
            mail.Dispose()
        End Sub


        ' Properties
        Public Property Attachments As String
            Get
                Return Me._attachments
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._attachments = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property BCC As String
            Get
                Return Me._BCC
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._BCC = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Body As String
            Get
                Return Me._body
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._body = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property CC As String
            Get
                Return Me._CC
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._CC = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property MailSent As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me._mailSent
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property MailServer As String
            Get
                Return Me._mailServer
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._mailServer = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Password As String
            Get
                Return Me._password
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._password = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Sender As String
            Get
                Return Me._sender
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._sender = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Subject As String
            Get
                Return Me._subject
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._subject = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property [To] As String
            Get
                Return Me._recepients
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._recepients = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Username As String
            Get
                Return Me._username
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._username = value
            End Set
        End Property


        ' Fields
        Private _attachments As String
        Private _BCC As String
        Private _body As String
        Private _CC As String
        Private _mailSent As Boolean
        Private _mailServer As String
        Private _password As String
        Private _recepients As String
        Private _sender As String
        Private _subject As String
        Private _username As String
    End Class
```

Code that sends emails:

```
Do While rd.Read

    Dim m As New LinksMailer.Mailer

    m.MailServer = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("mailServer")
    m.Username = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("mailUsername")
    m.Password = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("mailPassword")
    m.Sender = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("sender")
    m.To = Conversions.ToString(rd.Item("Email"))
    m.CC = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("Cc")
    m.BCC = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("Bcc")
    m.Subject = "Some subject...."
    m.Body = "Some HTML body..."
    m.SendMail()

    ' when I add this line everything works!!!
    ' Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
Loop
```

What is happening here???

Answer (score 2):

A developer I work with is responsible for emailing newsletters to a large (100k+) group of users monthly and built in a 400ms lag between each mail sent.  He does this to prevent mail servers from automatically listing him as a spammer.  It's possible you're running into SendMail security issues.  How many emails are you sending out at a time?  He arrived at the 400ms number from trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a late reply, I hope it may help the next reader

```
 Dim inte  As Integer
 Dim ji As Integer
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim inte As Integer = Grid.Rows.Count
            inte = inte - 1
            For ji = 0 To inte
                Dim email As String = Grid.Rows(ji).Cells(4).Text
                sendmail(email)
            Next ji
        End If

    End Sub
```

This code will be able to send the email to last row of grid
Hope it will work if not do apologize

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do not send large number of mails (up to 20), and mostly only one. But I noticed that when application needs to send one mail it does not get sent, if 3 mails needs to be sent, only first two are sent and so on. I do not think this is an issue here.